# Эквивалент метода noneMatch() Java в C#

Tags: java, c#

Подскажите, какой в данном слуачи будет эквивалент noneMatch() на C# в следующем Java коде

```
public static boolean isLowerCase(String text) {
        return text
            .codePoints()
            .noneMatch(Character::isUpperCase);
    }
```

Comment: В linq можно использовать `.All(x => char.IsLower(x))` - обратите внимание, что условие внутри инвертировано.

Comment: Либо, если нужна прямая аналогия, то будет `! ... .Any(x => x.IsUpper())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как говорится в [источнике](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/11/java-8-stream-nonematch-example/):

> Метод stream `noneMatch()` работает прямо противоположно методу `anyMatch()`, он возвращает `true`, если ни один из элементов потока не соответствует заданному предикату, он возвращает `false`, если какой-либо из элементов потока соответствует условию, заданному предикатом.

В C# нет прямого эквивалента, однако такого же результата можно добится через отрицание результата `Any()` - аналога `anyMatch()` в C#.

Пример:

```
var text = "Some text"
var isLower = !text.Any(symbol => char.IsUpper(symbol));
```

Другой вариант - использовать метод `All()`, который возвращает `true`, только если все члены последовательности удволетворяют предикат.

Пример:

```
var text = "Some text"
var isLower = text.All(symbol => char.IsLower(symbol));
```

Есть костыльный вариант:

```
var text = "Some text"
var isLower = text == text.ToLower();
```

Можно сделать красивое рассширение для удобства:

```
public static class StrinExtension
{
    public static bool IsLower(this string source)
        => source.All(symbol => symbol.IsLower());
}
```

Comment: +1, для краткости можно использовать `.Any(char.IsLower)`. Только Вы точно уверены, что у `string` есть `IsLower`? Это в какой-то версии такое появилось?

Comment: @KuzCode по ссылке `ToLower`

Comment: @defaultlocale а, ну такое бывает, я и слеповат чючють)))))

Comment: `codePoints` в Java возвращает IntStream, а именно: 32-битные **кодовые точки** Юникода. Весь предложенный вами код использует 16-битные **символы** Юникода. То есть в общем случае результат работы может быть другой (неправильный).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хорошее замечание, но я думаю это единственный простой эквивалент

Comment: Да, практически наверняка это подойдёт автору вопроса. Просто Юникод - дело тонкое и нюансов в его обработке столько, что я счёл своим долгом влезть с замечанием.